# Eliminating effectively-redundant entries with Inner Join

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The problem that we are trying to solve can be explained with the following illustrative example.

We have the following two tables:

```
CREATE table moniker_tbl
(
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  nickname VARCHAR(20),

  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);


CREATE table student_tbl
(
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  stipend INT,

  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO moniker_tbl(name, nickname) VALUES ('John Doe', 'Jonny'),
('John Doe', 'The Doe Man'), ('Richard Stevens', 'Rickie'),
('William Smith', 'Billy'), ('William Smith', 'Smithie');

INSERT INTO student_tbl(name, stipend) VALUES ('John Doe', '5000'),
('Richard Stevens', '7000'), ('William Smith', '6000');
```

We perform the following INNER JOIN operation:

```
SELECT t1.nickname, t2.stipend
FROM moniker_tbl AS t1
INNER JOIN student_tbl AS t2
ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

We get the following results:

```
+-------------+---------+
| nickname    | stipend |
+-------------+---------+
| Jonny       |    5000 |
| The Doe Man |    5000 |
| Rickie      |    7000 |
| Billy       |    6000 |
| Smithie     |    6000 |
+-------------+---------+
```

We would like the results to show only one entry per nickname e.g.

```
+-------------+---------+
| nickname    | stipend |
+-------------+---------+
| Jonny       |    5000 |
| Rickie      |    7000 |
| Billy       |    6000 |
+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: At the risk of being obvious, Which one?

Comment: Which is the "correct" nickname? How will you decide that? [or is that too obvious]

Comment: It looks like you want one row per distinct value of `stipend`, not nickname. But which nickname do you want for each row? Your requirements are not clear.

Comment: @MrR in our application it does not matter which nickname we choose.

Comment: @BillKarwin, no we want one row per name, irrespective of how many nicknames it resolves to.

Comment: @Strawberry in our application it does not matter which nickname we choose.

Comment: In your example above you have five distinct nicknames. You say you want one row per nickname. But the results you say you want only show three nicknames. Why do "The Doe Man" and "Smithie" not appear in your desired results? That's what we're asking. Something is clear to you, but you have not described it in your question.